# Boundary conditions in dielectric problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

> Q) A conducting sphere of radius R floats half submerged in a liquid
>   dielectric medium of permittivity $\epsilon_1$. The region above the
>   liquid is a gas of permittivity $\epsilon_2$. The total free charge on
>   the sphere is $ Q$. Find a radial inverse-square electric field
>   satisfying all boundary conditions and determine the free, bound, and
>   total charge densities at all points on the surface of the sphere.
>   Formulate an argument to show that this electric field is the actual
>   one.

By the condition that potential should be same at the interface between dielectric $1$ and dielectric $2$, we get that potential as a function of $r$ is same in both media.
But my question is that, when we use the second boundary condition, i.e., the normal components of Electric displacements have a difference of the free charge density on the interface, we get something weird.

$D$ inside the conducting sphere is $0$ and the potential is of the form $\frac{A}{r}$ due to spherical symmetry and boundary conditions.

$D1n$(Normal component of Electric displacement in dielectric 1) at $r=R= -\frac{\epsilon_1 A}{r^2}$
$D2n$(Normal component of Electric displacement in dielectric 2) at $r=R = -\frac{\epsilon_2 A}{r^2}$

So, using the conditions, we get:

$D1n - 0 =\sigma$

$D2n - 0 = \sigma$

Which is obviously wrong. So where did I make a mistake?

Comment: I could help you with finding the electric field intensity. You could construct a gaussian surface of radius $r$ around the sphere, and calculate the magnitude of the electric field intensity (which is radial) to be - $E = \dfrac{Q}{2\pi\epsilon_0(\epsilon_1+ \epsilon_2)r^2}$, for $r > a$. For $r < a$ , it is obvious that $E = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made an incorrect assumption about the surface charge density on the conducting sphere.
If you have a parallel plate capacitor with air between the plates there is a uniform charge density on the plates.
What does introducing a dielectric half way into the capacitor do to the surface charge density on the plates?

Comment: Oh right! How could I not know!